# Problem with resizing the simple bootstrap cover template

Tags: php, css, templates, resize, cover

i can't find a way to slightly increase the width of the bootstrap cover template.
Increasing the size in the css to @media doesn't change anything.

I guess it's very simple, but I can't figure out how to do it.
Sorry for the incompetence!

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you post the CSS which doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

In this template https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/cover/, In *cover.css* file you shall find the limiting factor of the container width to be this CSS rule: (I got this from inspecting the DOM in Dev Tools).

```
.cover-container {
    max-width: 42em;
}
```

So change that to a bigger max-width